# Time complexity with Big O notation for a called function

Tags: c++, time-complexity, knn

I read many resources about calculating `time complexity O(n)`. I applied what I understand on my code.

Bellow is my code and my attempt to find `time complexity`.

my code:

```
    float Euclidean_distance(int array_point_A[20], int  array_point_B[20]) {
    float sum = 0.0;
    float  w[20] = { 0.0847282, 0.0408621, 0.105036, 0.0619821, 0.0595455, 0.0416739, 0.0181147, 0.00592921,
     0.040049, 0.0766054, 0.0441091, 0.0376111, 0.0124285, 0.0733558, 0.0587338, 0.0303001, 0.0579207, 0.0449221,
          0.0530462, 0.0530462 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        float a = array_point_A[i] - array_point_B[i];
        float wieghted_distance = w[i] * (a * a); 
        sum += wieghted_distance;
    }
    return sqrt(sum);
}


int KNN_classifier(int X_train[4344][20], int Y_train[4344], int k, int data_point[20]) {

    // Calculate the distance between data_point and all points.    
    float array_dist[4344]{};
    int index_arr[4344]{} 
   for (int i = 0; i *< 4344; ++i) {
        array_dist[i] = Euclidean_distance(X_train[i], data_point);
        index_arr[i] = i;
    }
```

Now: for function `Euclidean_distance`it has `2 operations outside the loop` and `3 operations inside the loop that will iterate 20 times`. Thus, `2+3n` then we have `O(n)`.

Now: for function  `KNN_classifier`. it has a loop that will iterate `4344` times. Inside the loop , there is `2 operations`. so we have `2n` and then `O(n)`. // I am not sure about this solution.

This operation  `array_dist[i] = Euclidean_distance(X_train[i], data_point);` confused me.
So, do I need to include the `Euclidean_distance` time complexity in my calculation.  If so, I guess the time complexity will be `O(n^2)`. But the two loops has different bounds.

Please I need help !!!

Comment: Notice that you can have several parameters in bigO, `O(N*M)` is an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big-O notation only has meaning relative to one or more parameters, but you haven't described which values in your code are variable and which are constants.

As it is written, the function `KNN_classifier` is actually `O(1`) because  4344 is a fixed constand and 20 is a constant. If 20 is a constant and the size of `X_train` and `Y_train` is meant to vary as some number `n` then it is `O(n)`. If the 20 constant also varies as `m` then it is `O(n*m)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes. they are not constant. so, you mean the time complexity for `KNN_classifier` will be `O(N*M)`. not `O(N^2)` because `Euclidean_distance` is called inside `KNN_classifier` and it has a loop that has `M dimensions` and `N is the size of training data`  ????

Comment: if n = 4344 and m = 20 then it's n*m, yeah, how bout an upvote :)   ?

Comment: yes of course , thank you for your answer. I just accepted it